# Understanding Kivy properities and binding methods

Tags: python, properties, bind, kivy

I am having problems understanding the usage of custom Properities and ways of binding methods to events.
Here's my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

kivy_lang = '''
<MainWidget>:
    on_my_property: my_label.text = 'from button bind method via StringProperty' + my_property

    Label:
        id: my_label
        text: root.my_property
    Button:
        id: my_button
        text: 'intro button'

'''


class MainWidget(BoxLayout):
    # bind some properties
    my_property = StringProperty('0')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    #     if needed to do sth on widget construction
        self.ids.my_button.bind(on_press=self.my_method)


    def my_method(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.my_property = str(int(self.my_property)+1)
        self.ids.my_button.text = 'new'


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kivy_lang)
        return MainWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

When I run it it renders OK, but when I click a button, as a result I get
NameError: name 'my_property' is not defined

I tried binding method for Button in kv lang with (and removing whole '**init**()' on python side):

```
on_press: root.my_method
```

and then when I press button the app doesn't crash but nothing happens

Can someone explain me how to adjust this code to work?
I understand the code is a little 'mixed techniques' but I did it that way to get to know different approaches, so I would appreciate if You don't turn it all around :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ you are missing 'self' before 'my_property' in 'on_my_property' bindind, hence the crash

2/ in kv bindings. the python code is called as written, so you need '()' after 'root.my_method', or the statement has no effect.

Comment: Nice, thanks for quick reply - looks like I wasn't so far after all :)

so I need to remember:
1) & 2) - what is written after ':' in kv lang isn't really a binding at any point, 

**it's always a python code to execute 'as is'** when property updates (hence 'self.' is needed to refer to attribute/property in current instance of widget)